# controller does not convert json to viewmodel

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I'm passing two objects to my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSelectedQuote(CarQuoteRequestViewModel carModel, QuoteViewModel quoteModel)
 {
      return PartialView("_QuoteSelected", quoteModel);
 }
```

The AJAX call is the following (I've hardcoded the JSON string so you can see what it looks like, but normally I would use the ser $.ajax("getSelectedQuote", {

```
            //data: ko.toJSON({ model: self.selectedQuote, model1: $("#etape").serializeArray() }),
            data:  ko.toJSON({"quoteModel":{"ProductName":"Classic","MonthPrice":98.19,"QuarterPrice":291.64,"BiannualPrice":577.37,"YearPrice":1142.94,
    "CoverQuotesViewModel":[
    {"ProductName":"Classic","Label":"ResponsabilitÃ© Civile","IsVisible":false,"IsMandatory":false,"IsSelected":false,"YearPrice":338.17,"BiannualPrice":170.83,"QuarterPrice":86.29,"MonthPrice":29.05},        
    {"ProductName":"Classic","Label":"PremiÃ¨re Assistance 24h/24 (GRATUITE)","IsVisible":false,"IsMandatory":false,"IsSelected":false,"YearPrice":0,"BiannualPrice":0,"QuarterPrice":0,"MonthPrice":0},
    {"ProductName":"Classic","Label":"Dommage (DM TCC 0%)","IsVisible":false,"IsMandatory":false,"IsSelected":false,"YearPrice":717.47,"BiannualPrice":362.44,"QuarterPrice":183.07,"MonthPrice":61.64},
    {"ProductName":"Classic","Label":"Individuelle Circulation","IsVisible":false,"IsMandatory":false,"IsSelected":false,"YearPrice":67.9,"BiannualPrice":34.3,"QuarterPrice":17.33,"MonthPrice":5.83},
    {"ProductName":"Classic","Label":"Protection Juridique","IsVisible":false,"IsMandatory":false,"IsSelected":false,"YearPrice":19.4,"BiannualPrice":9.8,"QuarterPrice":4.95,"MonthPrice":1.67}
    ]},

"carModel": [
        {"name":"DriverInfoViewModel.DriverInfo.NoClaimsDegree","value":"1"},
            {"name":"DriverInfoViewModel.DriverInfo.DrivingLicenceDate","value":"2013-03-02"},
            {"name":"DriverInfoViewModel.DriverInfo.DisasterHistory","value":"MoreThanTwoDisasters"},
            {"name":"CarInfoViewModel.CarInfo.CarValue","value":"15000"},
            {"name":"CarInfoViewModel.CarInfo.AudioValue","value":"1000"},
            {"name":"CarInfoViewModel.CarInfo.EngineCapacity","value":"1500"},
            {"name":"CarInfoViewModel.CarInfo.AdditionalSeats","value":"1"},
            {"name":"CarInfoViewModel.CarInfo.FirstRegistration","value":"2013-03-02"}
       ]}),
            type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#custom").html(result);
                $("#etape").formwizard("show", "customize");
            }
        });
```

The strange thing, is that the QuoteViewModel  is perfectly rebuild when the controller is hit. However the CarQuoteRequestViewModel  object is not. The properties are empty.

The ViewModel objects are the following:

```
public class CarQuoteRequestViewModel : QuoteRequestViewModel
{       
    public CarInfoViewModel CarInfoViewModel { get; set; }
    public DriverInfoViewModel DriverInfoViewModel { get; set; }

    public CarQuoteRequestViewModel()
    {
        CarInfoViewModel = new CarInfoViewModel();
        DriverInfoViewModel = new DriverInfoViewModel();
    }
}


public class QuoteViewModel
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal MonthPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal QuarterPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal BiannualPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal YearPrice { get; set; }

    public List<CoverQuoteViewModel> CoverQuotesViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not posting all the nested objects for now, because it works fine for the QuoteViewModel. Do you have any idea what might be wrong with the CarQuoteRequestViewModel mapping from JSON ?

**EDIT**

As per Darin recommendation I've changed the JSON to:

```
  data: ko.toJSON({ "model": { "ProductName": "Classic", "MonthPrice": 98.19, "QuarterPrice": 291.64, "BiannualPrice": 577.37, "YearPrice": 1142.94,
                "CoverQuotesViewModel": [
    { "ProductName": "Classic", "Label": "ResponsabilitÃ© Civile", "IsVisible": false, "IsMandatory": false, "IsSelected": false, "YearPrice": 338.17, "BiannualPrice": 170.83, "QuarterPrice": 86.29, "MonthPrice": 29.05 },
    { "ProductName": "Classic", "Label": "PremiÃ¨re Assistance 24h/24 (GRATUITE)", "IsVisible": false, "IsMandatory": false, "IsSelected": false, "YearPrice": 0, "BiannualPrice": 0, "QuarterPrice": 0, "MonthPrice": 0 },
    { "ProductName": "Classic", "Label": "Dommage (DM TCC 0%)", "IsVisible": false, "IsMandatory": false, "IsSelected": false, "YearPrice": 717.47, "BiannualPrice": 362.44, "QuarterPrice": 183.07, "MonthPrice": 61.64 },
    { "ProductName": "Classic", "Label": "Individuelle Circulation", "IsVisible": false, "IsMandatory": false, "IsSelected": false, "YearPrice": 67.9, "BiannualPrice": 34.3, "QuarterPrice": 17.33, "MonthPrice": 5.83 },
    { "ProductName": "Classic", "Label": "Protection Juridique", "IsVisible": false, "IsMandatory": false, "IsSelected": false, "YearPrice": 19.4, "BiannualPrice": 9.8, "QuarterPrice": 4.95, "MonthPrice": 1.67 }
    ]
            },

                "model1":
        { "DriverInfoViewModel.DriverInfo.NoClaimsDegree" : "1",
            "DriverInfoViewModel.DriverInfo.DrivingLicenceDate" : "2013-03-02",
             "DriverInfoViewModel.DriverInfo.DisasterHistory" : "MoreThanTwoDisasters",
            "CarInfoViewModel.CarInfo.CarValue": "15000",
            "CarInfoViewModel.CarInfo.AudioValue" : "1000",
            "CarInfoViewModel.CarInfo.EngineCapacity" : "1500",
            "CarInfoViewModel.CarInfo.AdditionalSeats" : "1",
            "CarInfoViewModel.CarInfo.FirstRegistration" : "2013-03-02"
        }
            }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON you are passing a collection (notice the square brackets) of an object with properties `Name` and `Value`:

```
"carModel": [ ... ]
```

but your controller action expects a single `CarQuoteRequestViewModel`.

So either fix your JSON request or if you want to send multiple cars make sure that you use the proper type on your controller action.

I don't see any Name and Value properties on your `CarQuoteRequestViewModel`, so even if you change your controller action to take a collection of `CarQuoteRequestViewModel` it is unlikely that this is going to work. The JSON you are passing must conform to your model.

If you want to keep your `CarQuoteRequestViewModel` you should fix your JSON:

```
"carModel": {
    "carInfoViewModel": {
        ...
    },
    "driverInfoViewModel": {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

It looks like you are attempting to serialize some form element (`$('#etape')`) to JSON. You should not use the `serializeArray` method because this method generates incorrect JSON as I have already explained. You get a name/value collection. You could use the `serializeObject` method shown in [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/29407).

Comment: the json I've posted was generated by the following code: data: ko.toJSON({ model: self.selectedQuote, model1: $("#etape").serializeArray() }).  I do not want to pass an array indeed. Then what should the JSON look like (so I can test if it works) and then how do I generate the correct JSON (I've tried serialize instead of SerializeArray, but that gives me a string and it fails to convert both objects)

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right, the JSON was incorrect. Now it works with the JSON i've added to my original post. But the question remains : How do I generate that JSON string ????  If I use form.serializeArray I get the incorrect JSON string.

Comment: Use the `serializeObject` method from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/29407 I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: yes, I've been using the serializeObject method  from https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object, and it works great !